# PHP Session changes on sub pages

Tags: php, wordpress, session, subdirectory

I have a WordPress page, used as a community page for my gaming league at innerspherewars.eu.

For interaction with the league (putting in fight results, posting new attacks) however, I have created a "command section" in a subdirectory.

Is there a way to have the pages located under /subdirectory to have their own PHP session and coockie, other than the main page?

Comment: Why do you want to do so? Place that other stuff under another subdomain, or also place Wordpress in a subdirectory of your root

Comment: Well, when I started with the project some years ago, I wanted the users just to login with their main page accounts and then be taken to their game settings without a second user account. Back then, I did simply not think about using subdomains and it worked for years. Now, WP or one of the plugins, is using PHP sessions and interferes with my command section. I would simply prefer to use an own session for the command section, without the need of a sub domain, which would also mean,I'd have to change all links in the code etc.